# Taking whole json of translations language in en language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have rest_name attribute of `json` type and I am storing `json` of languages in it like `{"de": "abc", "en": "abc"......}`
but when I create a new record it stores whole above `json` like
`{"en": {"de": "abc", "en": "abc"......}}`

in model I have written like,

```
extend Mobility
translates :restaurant_name_translations, type: :string, fallbacks: {fr: :en, de: :en, es: :en, nl: :en, sv: :en, tr: :en, zh: :en, "en-GB": :en, "de-DE": :en, "fr-FR": :en, "es-ES": :en, "nl-NL": :en, "sv-SE": :en, "tr-TR": :en, "zh-Hans": :en}


# I want only to store like {"de": "abc", "en": "abc"......} in database
```

Comment: There is no `json` type in Ruby.

Comment: You might need to give more detail of your input data, I assume it has been badly formatted.